# Can ItemList be linked to a variety of other schema properties such as ItemPage, Vehicle, Property

Tags: schema.org

On a classifieds website, can the markup for the listing pages corresponding to various product categories (properties, vehicles, items & services) be combined with specific markup for the detailed product pages?

That is, using `ItemList` for the category listings and:

- `Property` (under `Intangible`) for properties (real estate),
- `Vehicle` (under `Product`) for cars,
- `ItemPage` (under `WebPage`) for items & services?

---

```
@type            ItemList
numberOfItems    ...
itemListElement 
     @type       WebPage
```

Or, for a different listing page:

```
@type        Property
```

Or, for a different listing page:

```
@type        Vehicle
```

Or, for a different listing page:

```
@type        ItemPage
```

Comment: 1) Do you ask what Schema.org allows / makes possible, or do you ask if it’s possible for getting a rich result (e.g., in Google Search)? If the latter, which rich result? 2) With "property", do you mean it in the sense of real estate? 3) Can you please [edit] your question and include a small structured data example that shows how you would implement it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @unor. 
1) Yes, At this stage I am asking whether Schema.org makes it possible. I admit I have to figure out the latter.
2) I have used "Property" interchangeably, indeed. The question is now edited to clarify the usage of the word.
3? I'm getting back to this

Comment: 3) Edited the Question to answer the 3rd point.

Comment: Thanks. I’m not sure I fully understand. You ask if it can be combined with the "specific markup for the detailed product pages", but your example only shows a list of these items. Do you ask if you can add the data about each vehicle on the listing page, too? Or do you ask if the vehicle on the listing page can be semantically linked with the same vehicle on the detail page? Or what do you mean with "combined"?

Comment: Thank you for asking for more clarifications. I am actually asking if on a listing page the ItemList container can hold a variety of ItemListElements of different types or if it's tied up to only a certain set of ItemList Elements. 
We've figured it out in the meantime and no, it seems that there are no restrictions in terms of the type of ItemListElement.
Many thanks for your support.